# Small random disturbance of a flat surface

Tags: plotting, random

I am trying to create an initial condition which is:

`1 + 0.05 rand(x,y)`
Here `rand` is a pseudorandom function distributed in the interval (-1,1). This surface represents a random disturbance that I would like to use as an initial condition for PDEs in `NDSolve`.

I assume I am being very silly when I try to use `RandomReal[]` as my random number generator for my random disturbance. How should I proceed with this.

```
L = 100;
Plot3D[
       1 - 0.05 (Cos[2 π x/L] + Sin[2 π x/L]) Cos[2 π y/L] RandomReal[],
       {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}
       ]
```

Obviously, this is wrong as this still retains the underlying Cos/Sin curve. How should I go about creating a random disturbance? 
$\delta\varepsilon\pi$

### Working example:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
Clear[Eq0, EvapThickFilm, h, Bo, ε, K1, \[Delta], Bi, m, r]
Eq0[h_, {Bo_, ε_, K1_, δ_, Bi_, m_, r_}] := D[h, t] + 
    Div[-h^3 Bo Grad[h] + 
      h^3 Grad[Laplacian[h]] + (δ h^3)/(Bi h + K1)^3 Grad[h] + 
      m (h/(K1 + Bi h))^2 Grad[h]] + ε/(
    Bi h + K1) + (r) D[D[(h^2/(K1 + Bi h)), x] h^3, x] == 0;
SetCoordinates[Cartesian[x, y, z]];
EvapThickFilm[Bo_, ε_, K1_, δ_, Bi_, m_, r_] := 
  Eq0[h[x, y, t], {Bo, ε, K1, δ, Bi, m, r}];
TraditionalForm[
  EvapThickFilm[Bo, ε, K1, δ, Bi, m, r]];


L = 2*92.389; TMax = 3100*100;
Off[NDSolve::mxsst];
Clear[Kvar];
Kvar[t_] :=  Piecewise[{{1, t <= 1}, {2, t > 1}}]
(* Ktemp = Array[0.001 + 0.001 #^2 &, 13] *)
hSol = h /. NDSolve[{
     (*Bo,ε,K1,δ,Bi,m,r*)

     EvapThickFilm[0.003, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0.025, 0],
     h[0, y, t] == h[L, y, t],
     h[x, 0, t] == h[x, L, t],
     (*h[x,y,0] == 1.1+Cos[x] Sin[2y] *)

     h[x, y, 0] == BSplineFunction[RandomReal[1, {30, 30, 1}]]
     },
    h,
    {x, 0, L},
    {y, 0, L},
    {t, 0, TMax},
    Method -> {"BDF", "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 1},
    MaxStepFraction -> 1/50
    ][[1]]
```

With the B-spline as suggested by Vitaliy Kaurov in the answer below, I have the following error:

> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t
>   == 0.`. >>
>
> ReplaceAll::reps: {(h^(0,0,1))[x,y,t]-0.009 h[x,y,t]^2
>   (h^(0,1,0))[x,y,t]^2-(0.05 h[x,y,t]^2
>   (h^(0,1,0))[x,y,t]^2)/(1+h[x,y,t])^3+<<13>>+h[x,y,t]^3
>   ((h^(0,4,0))[x,y,t]+(h^(2,2,0))[x,y,t])+3 h[x,y,t]^2
>   (h^(1,0,0))[x,y,t] ((h^(1,2,0))[x,y,t]+(h^(3,0,0))[x,y,t])+h[x,y,t]^3
>   ((h^(2,2,0))[x,y,t]+(h^(4,0,0))[x,y,t])==0,h[0,y,t]==h[184.778,y,t],h[<<1>>]==<<1>>,h[x,y,0]==BSplineFunction[{{0.,1.},{0.,1.}},<>]}
>   is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and
>   so cannot be used for replacing. >>

Comment: What is the matter with the "white noise" `Plot3D[1 + RandomReal[{-0.05, 0.05}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]`? That would be valid as an initial condition provided it were repeatable, which can be accomplished by memoizing it: `f[x_, y_] := f[x, y] = RandomReal[]; Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]`. Just watch out for uncontrolled growth in RAM used by `f`!

Comment: @whuber Good point. However, this seems rather computationally intensive.. like you point out.

Comment: Yes, but if that's what's intended... .  I rather suspect, though, that you might want to refine your concept of a "random disturbance." You are asking for a random spatial field and those have *structure*. What structure are you looking for? I have described one that has a particularly simple covariance function, but (consequently) the realizations are not even continuous.

Comment: @whuber Sorry, but I barely understand the tech language that you just used. I've included an example with the bspline thingy and it errors out.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process might get you started.

Comment: @whuber Thank you. I'll look at the link.

Comment: @drN it's likely you want non-white noise, if you plan to feed it into a PDE and don't know anything about stochastic differential equations. This means basically something that is coarse-grained; one way to get this in practice is to produce a coarse grid of white noise and interpolate (which is more or less what Vitaliy is doing).

Comment: @acl I have an inkling as to why I'm having an issue: my BSplineFunction isn't a function of x and y. How can I describe it to be a function of x and y? I think thats what NDSolve complains about when I try to use a spline surface.

Comment: @drN I don't know but if you do `bsf = Interpolation@Flatten[
    Table[{{x, y}, 1 + .05*RandomReal[{-1, 1}]},
     {x, 0, L + 1}, {y, 0, L + 1}], 1];` and then have as an ic `h[x, y, 0] == bsf[x, y]` it works (except I didn't fix the boundary conditions correctly)

Comment: @acl I think with a random number type ic, there would always be the ibcinc warning popping up. The whole `SplineClosed->True` helps with that. However, I am unable to use `BSplineFunction` in `NDSolve` as an ic. I was however, able to use ur suggestion with `bsf = Interpolation@Flatten[ Table[{{x, y}, 1 + .05*RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {x, 0, L + 1}, {y, 0, L + 1}], 1]`

Comment: @drN do take a look at it to make sure it's suitable for your purposes though; I think Vitaliy's suggestion is what I'd go for if I was doing this

Comment: @acl your suggestion did work as an initial condition. I have to see what I can do about Vitaly's Spline initial condition.

Comment: @acl, how do you plot `Interpolation@Flatten[ Table[{{x, y}, 1 + .05*RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {x, 0, L + 1}, {y, 0, L + 1}], 1]`? I tried putting it in a Plot3D function but that didn't work? Is that because its a `Table` now?

Comment: eg `t = With[
  {L = 10},
  Interpolation@
   Flatten[Table[{{x, y}, 1 + .05*RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {x, 0, 
      L + 1}, {y, 0, L + 1}], 1]
  ]` then `Plot3D[t[x, y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]`

Comment: @acl a wee bit off topic but are you guys on this website the ones who built mathematica? How do you all know *nearly* everything about it whilst I sit around scratching my head!!!! `:P`

Comment: @drN I certainly am not! some actually are yes. But I am not sure what impressed you that much here, I just happened to have done similar things in the past. It's no deep insight :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would use splines - it is very easy:

```
f = BSplineFunction[RandomReal[1, {30, 30, 1}], SplineClosed -> True]
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
       ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Opacity[.2]]
```

[image]

**SplineClosed -> True** makes sure you can use it with periodic boundary conditions in NDSolve. This is to show that indeed surface has periodic boundary conditions:

```
f[.7, 0] == f[.7, 1]
```

> True

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{f[x, 0], f[x, y]}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}],
 {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: So is this correct: `RandomReal` creates a random number array in the range (0,1) which is 30x30. Then this is fed into BSplineFunction to create a spline curve?

Comment: @drN Yes, but spline surface (not curve) which you cna use as analitic function: find derivative or feed into a NDSolve.

Comment: Well, using this as initial condition didn't give me agreeable results. My initial condition is `h[x,y,0]==BSplineFunction[RandomReal[1, {10, 10, 1}]]` for quite a complicated PDE... I'll see if I can include a simple working problem.

Comment: @drN Do you have to take care of boundary conditions?

Comment: It probably is as I need to use Periodic boundary conditions. However, mathematica didn't scream at me that the initial and bound conditions are inconsistent like it would usually do for bad ics/

Comment: I included an example. Maybe you can shed light on whats going on.

Comment: I am now almost certain that it isn't about boundary or initial conditions. I cant feed this spline into NDSolve is what is the problem. How does one do that?

Comment: @drN 1D spline works fine as initial condition. I am trying to figure out now how to make 2D surface work.

Comment: @ VitaliyKaurov, I try to use your answer `f = BSplineFunction[RandomReal[1, {30, 30, 1}], SplineClosed -> True]` to produce a small random disturbance of a plane in a square domain of [0,4*pi]*[0,4*pi] which has periodic boundary condition. But when I try, say f[9,0]==f[9,4*pi], MMA gives me `False`. I know you produce a disturbed surface in the domain [0,1]*[0,1], but how to get such surface in the domain, say [0,4*pi]*[0,4*pi]?

Answer (score 6):

For random disturbances that retain some smoothness, I turn to Perlin noise:

```
dot2 = With[{grad = Most[Tuples[{1, -1, 0}, {2}]]},
            Compile[{{gradIdx, _Integer}, {x, _Real}, {y, _Real}},
                    {x, y}.grad[[gradIdx + 1]]]];

fade = Compile[{{t, _Real}}, t*t*t/(3.*t*(t - 1.) + 1.), RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];

lerp = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {t, _Real}}, (1. - t)*x + t*y];

perlin2D = With[{perms = Apply[Join, ConstantArray[RandomSample[Range[0, 15]], 2]]},
                Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}},
                        Module[{xi, yi, xa, ya, u, v, g00, g10, g01, g11},

                               xi = Floor[x]; yi = Floor[y];
                               xa = x - xi; ya = y - yi;
                               xi = Mod[xi, 16] + 1; yi = Mod[yi, 16] + 1;

                               u = fade[xa]; v = fade[ya];

                               g00 = Mod[perms[[perms[[xi]] + yi]], 8];
                               g10 = Mod[perms[[perms[[xi + 1]] + yi]], 8];
                               g01 = Mod[perms[[perms[[xi]] + yi + 1]], 8];
                               g11 = Mod[perms[[perms[[xi + 1]] + yi + 1]], 8];

                        lerp[lerp[dot2[g00, xa, ya], dot2[g10, xa - 1, ya], u],
                             lerp[dot2[g01, xa, ya - 1], dot2[g11, xa - 1, ya - 1], u], v]],
                        CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
                        CompilationTarget -> "WVM"]];
```

I had constructed this version of 2D Perlin noise to have a period of $16$ in both of its arguments. Here's how a fundamental piece looks like:

```
Plot3D[perlin2D[x, y], {x, 0, 16}, {y, 0, 16},
       BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 75]
```

[image: basic Perlin noise]

One can use the noise function as is, scale the arguments or the function itself appropriately, or (as is common with how Perlin noise is used) sum so-called "octaves" of them:

```
Plot3D[perlin2D[x, y] + perlin2D[2 x, 2 y]/2 + perlin2D[4 x, 4 y]/4,
       {x, 0, 16}, {y, 0, 16}, BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 75]
```

[image: three octaves of Perlin noise]

Answer (score 5):

Vitaly's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15728/204) is correct in that it fantastically produces a splined random disturbace surface. However, I was unable to use it as an initial condition for my `NDSolve[...]`.

Based on [whuber's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15726/small-random-disturbance-of-a-flat-surface#comment46440_15726) and [acl's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15726/small-random-disturbance-of-a-flat-surface#comment46466_15726), I used :

```
bsf = Interpolation@Flatten[ Table[{{x, y}, 1 + .05*RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {x, 0, L + 1}, {y, 0, L + 1}], 1]
```

.. as the initial condition for my `NDSolve[...]`. Yes, `NDSolve` doesn't *like* this and complains about a mismatch in the initial and boundary conditions with my favorite `ibcinc` warning message but I think it is smart enough to reconcile these boundary differences and I am able to solve my partial differential equation satisfactorily.

I tried splining this random surface like whuber and acl suggested but it hasn't worked. If anyone can provide an initial condition that has the `SplineClosed->True` feature that can be used in `NDSolve`, that would be truly awesome!

### Here is the PDE being solved:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
Clear[Eq0, EvapThickFilm, h, Bo, \[Epsilon], K1, \[Delta], Bi, m, r]
Eq0[h_, {Bo_, \[Epsilon]_, K1_, \[Delta]_, Bi_, m_, r_}] := \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]h\) + 
        Div[-h^3 Bo Grad[h] + 

      h^3 Grad[Laplacian[h]] + (\[Delta] h^3)/(Bi h + K1)^3 Grad[
        h] + 
            m (h/(K1 + Bi h))^2 Grad[h]] + \[Epsilon]/(
          Bi h + K1) + (r) D[D[(h^2/(K1 + Bi h)), x] h^3, x] == 0;
SetCoordinates[Cartesian[x, y, z]];
EvapThickFilm[Bo_, \[Epsilon]_, K1_, \[Delta]_, Bi_, m_, r_] := 
    Eq0[h[x, y, t], {Bo, \[Epsilon], K1, \[Delta], Bi, m, r}];
TraditionalForm[
    EvapThickFilm[Bo, \[Epsilon], K1, \[Delta], Bi, m, r]];





L = 2*92.389; TMax = 3100*100;
Off[NDSolve::mxsst];
Clear[Kvar];
bsf = Interpolation@
   Flatten[Table[{{x, y}, 1 + .05*RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {x, 0, 
      L + 1}, {y, 0, L + 1}], 1];
Kvar[t_] :=  Piecewise[{{1, t <= 1}, {2, t > 1}}]
(*Ktemp = Array[0.001+0.001#^2&,13]*)
hSol = h /. NDSolve[{
          (*Bo,\[Epsilon],K1,\[Delta],Bi,m,r*)

          EvapThickFilm[0.003, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0.025, 0],
          h[0, y, t] == h[L, y, t],
          h[x, 0, t] == h[x, L, t],
          (*h[x,y,0] == 1.1+Cos[x] Sin[2y] *)

          h[x, y, 0] == bsf[x, y]
          },
        h,
        {x, 0, L},
        {y, 0, L},
        {t, 0, TMax},
        Method -> {"BDF", "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 1},
        MaxStepFraction -> 1/50
        ][[1]]
```

### And the initial condition being plotted:

[image]