# Generating animations of clouds with Mathematica

Tags: image-processing, random, generative-art

I'd like to generate some visually-pleasing animations of clouds, fog or smoke with *Mathematica*. My idea of "visually-pleasing" is along the lines of one of the images on the Wikipedia article for [random Perlin noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise).

[image]

> Image description: *"Perlin noise rescaled and added into itself to create fractal noise."*

Based on the example [MATLAB code found here](http://www.semifluid.com/2012/12/05/2d-and-3d-perlin-noise-in-matlab/), I wrote the following function in *Mathematica*:

```
perlin3D[n_, t_, r_] := Module[{s, w, i, d},
  s = ConstantArray[0., {t, n, n}];
  w = n;
  i = 0;
  While[w > 3,
   i++;
   d = GaussianFilter[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {t, n, n}], r*i];
   s = s + i*d;
   w = w - Ceiling[w/2 - 1];
   ];
  s = (s - Min@s)/(Max@s - Min@s)
  ]
```

The results are OK, but not as good as I'd like. It's not as smooth as the example image above, nor is the image contrast as strong.

```
(* Generate 100 frames of 128*128 pixels *)
res = perlin3D[128, 100, 4];
imgres = Image@# &/@ res;
ListAnimate[imgres, 16]
```

[image]

How can I improve the quality of the generation using *Mathematica*, and is there anyway to speed it up for larger and/or longer animations?

### Update

The contrast can be improved a little, as pointed out by N.J.Evans in a comment, by removing the first and last few frames before scaling, namely `s = s[[r*i ;; -r*i]]`. However it's still not as "fog-like" as the Wikipedia example.

[image]

Comment: I think your Gaussian filter is being applied along the t dimensions, so your dynamic range is dominated by the the first and last frames, where fewer terms have been included in the filtering. That cleans up if you take only parts `s=s[[r*i;;-r*i]]`. Of course make sure that t is bigger than 2*r*i.

Comment: That does indeed improve the contrast, well spotted!

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4829/5478

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is a 2D Gaussian random field with a $1/k^2$ spectrum and linear dispersion $\omega \propto k$. I clip the field to positive values and square root it to give an edge to the "clouds".

```
n = 256;
k2 = Outer[Plus, #, #] &[RotateRight[N@Range[-n, n - 1, 2]/n, n/2]^2];

spectrum = With[{d := RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {n, n}]},
   (1/n) (d + I d)/(0.000001 + k2)]; 
spectrum[[1, 1]] *= 0;

im[p_] := Clip[Re[InverseFourier[spectrum Exp[I p]]], {0, ∞}]^0.5

p0 = p = Sqrt[k2];

Dynamic @ Image @ im[p0 += p]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, +1 - with a bit of tweaking does the job I was after. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 15):

Nice cloud-like images can be generated by summing "octaves" of any of a number of continuous noise functions. [Perlin noise](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24730) is one possibility, as mentioned in the OP; here, I'll present a slightly simpler noise function termed *lattice convolution noise*. The following implementation is adapted from [Ebert *et al.*'s book](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=F4t-5zSsqr4C&pg=PA78), with a few of my own tweaks:

```
lcnoise = With[{perm = Mod[(112 # + 185) # + 111, 256, 1] &, 
                mncub = Compile[{{r, _Real}}, 
                                Which[0 <= r < 1, 16 + r^2 (21 r - 36),
                                      1 <= r < 2, 32 + r (-60 + (36 - 7 r) r),
                                      True, 0]/18, 
                                RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}], n = 256, 
                vals = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 256]},
               Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {z, _Real}},
                       Module[{s = 0., fx, fy, fz, ix, iy, iz},
                              ix = Floor[x]; iy = Floor[y]; iz = Floor[z];
                              fx = x - ix + 1.; fy = y - iy + 1.; fz = z - iz + 1.;
                              Do[s += vals[[Fold[perm[Mod[#1 + #2, n, 1]] &, 0,
                                                 {iz + k, iy + j, ix + i}]]]
                                      mncub[Norm[{i - fx, j - fy, k - fz}]],
                                 {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}, {k, 0, 3}]; s], 
                       CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}, 
                       RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]];
```

To get clouds, we can do this:

```
clouds =
    Table[DensityPlot[Clip[Sum[lcnoise[2^k x, 2^k t, 2^k y]/2^k, {k, 0, 3}], {0, 1}],
                      {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
                      ColorFunction -> (Lighter[RGBColor[0.53, 0.81, 0.92], #] &),
                      Frame -> False], {t, 0, 5, 1/4}];

ListAnimate[clouds]
```

[image: clouds]

Comment: This is fun! Thanks!