# Generate white noise in 2D

Tags: functions, programming, random

I am trying to generate a random (white noise) signal, as mentioned in the section ***Frequency Synthesis of Landscapes (and clouds)*** on [this](http://paulbourke.net/fractals/noise/) website. The problem I have is that I do not know if `WhiteNoiseProcess` is the right function to make white noise in 2D.

I have tried it in the following way without success:

```
SeedRandom[1234];
test = RandomFunction[
    WhiteNoiseProcess[NormalDistribution[]], {0, 256}, 2]["ValueList"];

ListPlot[Transpose@test]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that `Dimension[test]` is `{2, 257}`, which isn't what I want.

These are the kind of pictures that I want to make:

[image: I want make this]

I would like for you to please guide me to know how to do this in Mathematica. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Paul Nylander implemented frequency-filtered random noise [here](http://bugman123.com/Fractals/index.html). I made a slight modification of it [here](https://tpfto.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/on-making-simulated-landscapes/).

Comment: I think this answer is actually exactly the process you want: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80519/38205

Comment: @J.M. I really like your modification, I'm still waiting for your technique for bigger islands, I will review your code in detail to learn more, thanks for the recommendation

Comment: @b3m2a1  Maybe with the answer you gave on the pink noise,you will find that there is a relationship between perlin noise and pink noise or not. I am reviewing it to draw my conclusions, excellent recommendation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Update:

Just for fun, here's the process I think you were trying to implement. Wikipedia suggested to me that it was called pink noise, so we'll use pink names.

```
pinkify =
  Compile[
   {{data, _Complex, 2}, {center, _Real, 1}, {p, _Real}},
   MapIndexed[
    #/(Norm[#2 - center]^p) &,
    data,
    {2}
    ]
   ];
pinkNoiseTransform[
   data : {{__}, ___}, 
   center : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} | Automatic : Automatic,
   p : _?NumericQ : 1,
   fn : Except[_?NumericQ] : Abs
   ] :=
  Map[
   fn,
   InverseFourier@
    pinkify[Fourier[data],
     If[IntegerQ[#], # + .8, #] & /@ 
      Replace[center, Automatic :> Dimensions[data]/2],
     p
     ],
   {2}
   ];
pinkNoiseTransform[i : _Integer | {_Integer, _Integer}, r___] :=
 
 pinkNoiseTransform[whiteNoise2D[i], r]
```

I think the center point we assign minus the position in the matrix is `f`, so that's what I'm using `1/f`.

Here's an example:

```
dims = {100, 100};
data = whiteNoise2D[dims];
centralFrequency = dims/2;
power = 1.8;
pinky = pinkNoiseTransform[data, centralFrequency, power, Norm];

Image[
 Rescale[pinky, MinMax[pinky], {1, 0}],
 ColorSpace -> "Grayscale",
 ImageSize -> {300, 300},
 Interleaving -> True
 ]
```

[image]

One cool thing is that we can use the `Re` and `Im` parts of our data as different channels:

```
rePink =
  pinkNoiseTransform[data, centralFrequency, power, Re];
imPink =
  pinkNoiseTransform[data, centralFrequency, power, Im];

Image[
 MapThread[
  List,
  {
   Rescale[pinky, {0, 1}, {1, 0}],
   Rescale[rePink, {0, 1}, {1, 0}],
   Rescale[imPink, {0, 1}, {1, 0}]
   },
  2],
 ColorSpace -> "RGB",
 ImageSize -> {300, 300},
 Interleaving -> True
 ]
```

[image: asd2]

Finally, here's some 3D terrain from a smaller version of this (note that anything except `PerformanceGoal->"Speed"` gives too jagged as surface):

```
terrain =
  Join @@
   MapIndexed[
    Append[#2, #] &,
    pinkNoiseTransform[350, centralFrequency, power],
    {2}
    ];

ListPlot3D[terrain,
 ColorFunction -> "GreenBrownTerrain",
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"
 ]
```

[image: fdsfd]

---

I think you've got the wrong idea about what it's generating. The `2` simply means do 2 traces.

Try this:

```
whiteNoise2D[n_Integer] :=
  whiteNoise2D[{n, n}];
whiteNoise2D[{n_, m_}] :=
  
  RandomFunction[WhiteNoiseProcess[], {0, n}, m]["ValueList"];
whiteNoiseImage[{n_, m_}, size_: Automatic] :=
 
 Image[whiteNoise2D[{n, m}],
  ImageSize -> Replace[size, Automatic :> {n, m}]
  ]

Image[Rescale[whiteNoise2D[{500, 500}]],
 ImageSize -> {250, 250}]
```

[image: asd]

Comment: I might do it as `whiteNoise2D[n_Integer] := whiteNoise2D[{n, n}]; whiteNoise2D[{n_, m_}] := RandomFunction[WhiteNoiseProcess[], {0, n}, m]["ValueList"];` and then `Image[Rescale[whiteNoise2D[{500, 500}]]]`.

Comment: @J.M. I like that setup better. I'll change mine.

Comment: Your results seem to have spatially varying contrast along some diagonal bands. I'm pretty sure that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: @Rahul Hm. That seems to be correlated to my choice of .00001 as a factor to push it away from division by 0 points. .8 still has fuzzy band parts, just not regular and not on the diagonal. Less than .8 seems to show regular bands.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thanks for helping me implement the algorithm I showed, it's very funny to use pink names, but Wikipedia suggests it. I am trying to understand the code you provided, for this reason I hardly comment on your answer. You were right about how wrong I was using the 2 in the WhiteNoiseProcess command.

Comment: @b3m2a1  I'm still testing your code. Any question that arise, I'll tell you, hoping you can help me, thanks again

Answer (score 8):

We can use `RandomVariate` like this to generate white noise:

```
RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[], {256, 256}] // Image
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {256, 256}] // Image
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To just get the image, there is also `RandomImage`:

```
RandomImage[]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
RandomImage[NormalDistribution[]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The underlying data can be retrieved using `ImageData`.

The 3D visualization in the screenshot in the question is the same underlying data visualized with a `ListPlot3D` like function:

```
ListPlot3D[
 RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[], {256, 256}],
 ColorFunction -> GrayLevel
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPlot3D[
 RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {256, 256}],
 ColorFunction -> GrayLevel
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: C.E. Thank you for giving me other commands that serve to do what I want, I will try to do the following steps of the section mentioned above, to better understand the algorithm of the author and the solutions that the other members of this group have proposed